# Horizontal brace with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have two nodes next to each other but the right node is higher vertically.

I am trying to draw a brace. I'm using

```
\draw [decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=10pt, raise=2.5pt}] (fill_form.south east) -- (obtain_information.south west) node [red, midway, sloped, below=0.5cm] {my text};
```

Which produces

[image]

I have used `point1.south west` and `point2.south east` but since they are not positioned equally vertically, the brace will be angled. I want it to be a straight horizontal brace.

Comment: Don't forget that you can and should [*accept* the answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1853/80176) that best solves the question! Our reputations depend on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tikz can automatically deal with this sort of alignment. Try using the following:

```
\draw [decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=10pt, raise=2.5pt}] (fill_form.south east -- (fill_form.south east -| obtain_information.south west)) node [red, midway, sloped, below=0.5cm] {my text};
```

The `-|` and the `|-` path operations are documented in the [pgf/tikz manual](http://paws.wcu.edu/tsfoguel/tikzpgfmanual.pdf) on page 92.

The `-|` operator, for example, will calculate the intersection of a horizontal line passing through the point preceding the operator and a vertical line passing through the point following the operator.